# Why am I getting the JS error in line one of my script Syntax error: invalid or unexpected token?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I'm trying to make the picture on the index.html page change when you push the button.  Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="lolcatButton">Show me the LOLCat!</button>
  <br><br>
  <img id="lolcatImage" src=https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.skillcrush.com/skillcrush/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/cat5.jpg>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

---

And here's my js:

```
var lolcatButton = document.getElementById(“lolcatButton”);    
var lolcatImage = document.getElementById(“lolcatImage”);    
var image = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.skillcrush.com/skillcrush/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/cat4.jpg";     

var showMeTheLolcat = function(){    
    lolcatImage.src = image;    
};     

lolcatButton.addEventListener(“click”, showMeTheLolcat);
```

---

I'm getting an error on line 1 of the js "uncaught syntaxerror: invalid or unexpected token."

Does anyone have any ideas?  Thank you very much!

Comment: Does your code actually have the smart quotes around "lolcatbutton" and "click"?  i.e. the `“` and `”` characters that are not actually `"`.

Comment: Note that normally for "unexpected token" errors, if you click the line number of the error in the console it will take you to that line and highlight the token in question.

Answer (score 2):

```
var lolcatButton = document.getElementById("lolcatButton");
```

Change the **”** to **"**. And the other lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can reorganize your code like this:

```
<button id="lolcatButton" onclick="showMeTheLolcat()">Show me the LOLCat!</button>
  <br><br>
<img id="lolcatImage" src=https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.skillcrush.com/skillcrush/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/cat5.jpg>


<script>
function showMeTheLolcat() {
var image = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.skillcrush.com/skillcrush/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/cat4.jpg";
lolcatImage.src = image;
}
</script>
```

[Try it on jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/brahimthebig/quyqaksf/).